# link html button to java activity

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I'm making an Android app to my book I have an html page I want to add a button on it which is linked to this Java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // listeners of our two buttons
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.buttonShareTextUrl:
                    shareTextUrl();
                    break;


            }
        }
    };

    // our buttons
    findViewById(R.id.buttonShareTextUrl).setOnClickListener(handler);


}

// Method to share either text or URL.
private void shareTextUrl() {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "book");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sohaibm.assrar_bac");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share with"));
}
```

}

so I want you to give me an HTML code of the page that contains the button linked to this activity and thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If you use `WebView` to show book content you can use `WebViewClient`:

```
WebViewClient mWebClient = new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("handle:")){
                // do something
                return true;
            }

            else{
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebClient);
```

And your link should be:

```
<a href="handle://it.to.me">Link text</a>
```

Comment: would you please explane where should i put the code

Comment: @Sohaibm96 java code - in on Create() after ininialize WebView​ (after assign it with findViewById or something else you might use).
HTML code - whatever you want in your HTML page file

Comment: 39 I don't understand much in developing languages, please edit the code as what it is supposed to be and give it to me and tell me in which type or name of file should I put it, I just want one button to do the share like I said first and thank you so much for your Patience

Comment: @Sohaibm96 firstly tell me, do you use WebView?

Comment: i dont know what is web view i just edit some book app with my book content

Comment: @Sohaibm96 sorry, but I can not give you what you want because I don't know do you use WebView or not. My answer should help only if you're using the webView. 
.. Ok, just tell me if you post all code from your Mainacitivity? And, is there WevView tag (<WebView />) exist in activity_main.xml?

Comment: i dont know how i judt edit some book if you want i will send you the file just give me your fb or anythnig you have to talk thnk you man

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**Html Page:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function moveToScreenTwo() {
        Android.moveToNextScreen();
        }
        </script>

    </head>

  <body>
     <div>
            <input type="button" value="Locate" onClick="moveToScreenTwo()" />
        </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**FirstACtivity.java:**

```
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.load_url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 if (new File(url).exists()) {
            webView.loadUrl(FILENAME_PREFIX + url);
            Log.d("fileurl", "" + FILENAME_PREFIX + url);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        }
  //Class to be injected in Web page
    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void moveToNextScreen() {

            Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
     }
```

For more Reference: Check [this tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/).

Comment: it didint work i puted the first code in 001.htm
an i created FirstACtivity.java i puted the second code in the app i hadd just one button when i clilck nothing happend what should i do